# specific response to specific clients while making requests at the same time to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, nodes, ccxt

Is there any way to get responses to a specific client when another client has a different request at the same time to the same server?
This is code snippet for an exchange server. The given function is present in a library named "ccxt", this function "exchange.fetchMarkets()" has an API which requests to a third party server which is an exchange server like 'bitfinex', 'crex24', 'binance', etc. The issue I am facing is when one client is requesting for an exchange like 'crex24' at the same time when another client is requesting for different exchange like 'binance', they are getting the same response as the function calls for the last recent exchange.
I want it to give responses according to the client's requests independent of each other.

this one is controller function:

```
const ccxt = require("ccxt");

exports.fetchMarkets = function(req, res){

  let API = req.params.exchangeId;
  let exchange = new ccxt[API]();

  if (exchange.has["fetchMarkets"]) {
    try{
        var markets = await exchange.fetchMarkets();
        res.send(markets)
    }catch (err) {
          let error = String(err);
          res.send({ failed: error });
    }
  }else{
    res.send({loadMarkets : "not available"})
  }
}
```

This is end point for the server request:

```
app.route('/markets/:exchangeId')
    .get(exchange.fetchMarkets)
```

Here you can find the ccxt library: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual and can be included in the project by "npm install ccxt"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the code you mentioned wouldn't work the way you are expecting it to work. I created a small app and it is working as expected. You can check here

https://repl.it/repls/IllfatedStrangeRepo

I am hitting four different request with different ids and I am getting different response.

Hope it clear the doubts.